# Are review audits enabled on Magento SE?

Tags: discussion

I recently discovered that some SE sites have review audit tests: [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)

I was just wondering if such feature was enabled on Magento SE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I never got them here, but on StackOverflow I only see them after reviewing a certain amount of posts in a row and the review queues on this site are never that long so I assume that's the only reason.

Comment: Never got them either but I haven't been active on SE for long.